# How to make Scons build object files in a separate folder

Tags: python, scons

I'm working on a project which we used to compile using make. Now we wanna use scons instead so I've created a Sconstruct file that seems to handle this just fine.

Nevertheless, I'm greatly dissatisfied with the location where scons puts .o files (right next to my source files (.c), which is annoying) and i can't seem to understand how to make it create them in a specific folder during the build.

I've tried several (quite a lot) "VariantDir()", "env.VariantDir()", "variant_dir=...", etc... calls but none have worked for me yet. All I'm asking for is an option that would enable me to choose the folder where .o files will go so that they don't end up mixed with my source files.

Here's a taste of what I've done so far :

```
### Imports ###
import os

### Environment de compilation ###

# Dossier et nom du binaire
binFolder = 'bin/'
binName = 'sc.bin'

# Outils de l'environnement
env = DefaultEnvironment(
    tools = [ 'gcc', 'link' ],
)

# Chaine de compilation
env.PrependENVPath('PATH', os.path.abspath('path/to/cross/compiler'))
prefix = 'cross-compiler-prefix'
env['CC'] = prefix + env['CC']


### Fichiers a compiler ###
srcFiles = [ 
    'some',
    'source',
    'files'
]

### Dossiers a inclure (headers) ###
includeFolders = [ 
    'some',
    'include',
    'folders'
]

### Flags de compilation ###
compilationFlags = '-some -compilation -flags'

### Librairies externes ##
libs = [
    'some',
    'libraries'
]

### Regle de generation sc.bin  ###
sc_multi = env.Program(
    binFolder+binName,
    srcFiles,
    CDEFINES = {'SOME_MACRO':'SOME_VALUE'},
    CPPPATH = includeFolders,
    CFLAGS = compilationFlags,
    LIBS = libs,
)

# Par default, on genere la cible sc_multi
Default(sc_multi)
Alias('sc_multi', sc_multi)
```

If anyone has insight, please share as I nearly don't have any hair left.
Thx !

Comment: Move your current sources (together with the SConstruct you have) into a new subfolder "src". Then apply the recipes from the [SCons User Guide](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html), especially chap. 14 "Hierarchical Builds" and chap. 15 "Separating Source and Build Directories". **Don't** use `VariantDir()` directly, but the `variant_dir=` option of the `SConscript()` call instead. That should make it work automatically...

Comment: You could also have a look at my [SCons Talks Repo](https://bitbucket.org/dirkbaechle/scons_talks), especially the folder "`pyconde2013/examples/exvar`" where you'll find a working example.

Comment: Problems are : 
1 - the source files are part of a git submodule which does not belong to me. Meaning I can't upstream changes to it, therefore can't "move my current sources into a new subfolder"...
2 - I don't have an Sconscript file and, as a matter of fact, I'd greatly appreciate not to have to create one (I had one makefile, is it not possible to just have one Sconstruct file ?)

Comment: If you plan to have your object files in a separate folder, using variant directories is the canonical way. Using variant directories is the most easy if multiple SConstructs/SConscripts (preferably one in each subfolder with sources or other build files) are created. You can probably do it with one SConstruct, but it's not easy to setup and maintain...have a pick. You can also create a second `SConscript` on the top-level (next to your `SConstruct`) and call that in the `SConcript()` method.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074062/why-does-scons-variantdir-not-put-output-in-the-given-directory

Comment: Why wouldn't it be easy to setup with just one Sconstruct file ? Isn't it the kind of feature one wants working out of the box ? (I'm seriously angry at scons right now, this truly is trivial with make and I hate seeing my time wasted on such a petty issue...).
Anyway, i've tried renaming Sconstruct to Sconscript, then I created Sconscript which contained a single Sconscript() call with the "variant_dir=bin" option. I got my object files still mixed up with my source files + my Sconstruct got copied for god know what reason to the build folder + the build failed.
I give up. -1 for scons IMO.

Comment: Thx a lot for trying to help anyway @dirkbaechle !

Comment: Are the source files in the same directory as the SConstruct? Or as it sounds like from above, they are located in a subdirectory which maps to a git submodule?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force Scons output (exe, obj, lib & dll) to specific build directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720142/how-to-force-scons-output-exe-obj-lib-dll-to-specific-build-directory)

Comment: @Fointard you can use VariantDir() directly and then you just reference all the files in the variant dir and not the source dir.

Answer (score -1):

Ok. I'm going to assume based on your comments above that you are really talking about source files in a subdirectory (or at least another directory) from where your SConstruct is located

Let's assume your tree looks like this:

```
 - SConstruct
 - Git_Submodule_Directory
     |--- a.c
     |--- b.c
 - bin
     |--- a.o
     |--- b.o
```

Here's the SConstruct:

```
env=Environment()

binName='my_favorite'
### Fichiers a compiler ###
srcFiles = [ 
    'a.c',
    'b.c',
]

### Dossiers a inclure (headers) ###
includeFolders = [ 
    'git-submodule',
]

### Flags de compilation ###
compilationFlags = '-some -compilation -flags'

### Librairies externes ##
libs = [
    'm',
]

VariantDir('bin','git-submodule')

var_src = ["#bin/"+f for f in srcFiles]


### Regle de generation sc.bin  ###
sc_multi = env.Program(
    "#bin/"+binName,
    var_src,
    CDEFINES = {'SOME_MACRO':'SOME_VALUE'},
    CPPPATH = includeFolders,
    CFLAGS = compilationFlags,
    LIBS = libs,
)

# Par default, on genere la cible sc_multi
Default(sc_multi)
Alias('sc_multi', sc_multi)
```

git-submodule/a.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void another()
{
    printf("Another\n");
}
```

git-submodule/b.c

```
/* Hello World program */

#include<stdio.h>

extern void another();

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    another();
    return(0);
}
```

Does this do what you're looking for?
Build output:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
gcc -o bin/a.o -c -Igit-submodule bin/a.c
gcc -o bin/b.o -c -Igit-submodule bin/b.c
gcc -o bin/my_favorite bin/a.o bin/b.o -lm
scons: done building targets.
```

Note: you could add duplicate=0 to the VariantDir() then the output would be:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
gcc -o bin/a.o -c -Igit-submodule git-submodule/a.c
gcc -o bin/b.o -c -Igit-submodule git-submodule/b.c
gcc -o bin/my_favorite bin/a.o bin/b.o -lm
scons: done building targets.
```