# How to put objects into a separated build folder in SCons?

Tags: scons

I have this very simple project:

```
.
├── hello.c
├── lib
│   ├── foo.c
│   ├── foo.h
│   └── SConstruct
├── Makefile
└── SConstruct
```

After the build I would like to get this:

```
.
├── build
│   ├── hello
│   ├── hello.o
│   └── lib
│       ├── libfoo.a
│       └── foo.o
│
├── config.log
├── hello.c
├── lib
│   ├── foo.c
│   ├── foo.h
│   └── SConstruct
├── Makefile
└── SConstruct
```

I tried to add

```
VariantDir('build', '.')
```

But it doesn't work. Here is my `SConstruct` file

```
env = Environment(CC = 'gcc',
    CCFLAGS=['-O2', '-std=c99'],
)

Progress(['-\r', '\\\r', '|\r', '/\r'], interval=5)
env.Program('Hello', 'hello.c',
    LIBS=['foo'],
    LIBPATH='lib/',
    CPPPATH=['lib']
)
Decider('MD5-timestamp')

VariantDir('build', '.')
SConscript(['lib/SConstruct'])
```

**Edit**

I also tried to add the `variant_dir` directly to the `SConscript` directive:

```
SConscript(['lib/SConstruct'], variant_dir='build')
```

But I have an error:

```
$ scons -Q
gcc -o Hello hello.o -Llib -lfoo
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfoo
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: *** [Hello] Error 1
```

It seems SCons does not consider the `CPPPATH` anymore because I don't have any `-Ilib` during the build.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074062/why-does-scons-variantdir-not-put-output-in-the-given-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `VariantDir()` method directly, but the `variant_dir` keyword of the `SConscript` call instead. For this, it would be a good idea to move your sources into a separate "`src`" folder (see example below).

The relevant chapter in the [User Guide](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html) is 15 "Separating Source and Build Directories".

You can also find a working example at https://bitbucket.org/dirkbaechle/scons_talks in the `pyconde_2013/examples/exvar` folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have edited my question with your suggestion. I still have some issues.

Comment: That's because your `hello` target is **not** within the `lib` folder...so it's not under the influence of the variant dir setting. That's also why I suggest to move all your sources to a separate subfolder "src" first. Then it's easier to have all files in the subfolder being affected by the `variant_dir` option.

Comment: Well, so you don't really answer my question. I would like to achieve what I asked in my question. I want all the objects to be located into the `build` folder. This is something easily achievable with `make` or `cmake`, I am expecting SCons to be able to do the same :(

Comment: Okay, but you didn't mention that reorganising your source tree for reaching the specified goal is actually "out of question". It looks (judging from your other question) as if you're trying to compare build tools, in order to see whether SCons could be a fit for you. If the same implicit assumption ("won't nudge regarding project structure") applies to any future questions, please make this more obvious up-front.

Comment: You're right. I should have made my question more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the above:

```
env = Environment(CC = 'gcc',
    CCFLAGS=['-O2', '-std=c99'],
)

Progress(['-\r', '\\\r', '|\r', '/\r'], interval=5)

# explicitly specify target dir and file base so object 
# isn't in source directory.
object = env.Object('build/hello','hello.c')

env.Program('Hello', object,
    LIBS=['foo'],
    LIBPATH='build/lib/',
    CPPPATH=['build/lib']
)


Decider('MD5-timestamp')

VariantDir('build', '.')
SConscript('lib/SConstruct','build/lib')
```

Since you don't want to move source files into a subdir of the directory the SConstruct is to make this work, you'll need to manually specify the target directories (This is in line with make's functionality)

Comment: I get this error `scons: *** Export of non-existent variable ''build/lib''`. The other issue is that SCons copies the source code into the build repository which is not my goal.